# Read properties file and substitute the value in template file through Ant script

Tags: windows, ant

I have two files local.properties.template and other is test.properties file.

local.properties.tamplate looks like

```
dir.source=@deploy.dir@/data/source
dir.storage=@deploy.dir@/data/storage
dir.reports=@deploy.dir@/data/reports
dir.scripts=@deploy.dir@/data/scripts
dir.dictionary=@deploy.dir@/data/dictionary
moveit.dir=@moveit.dir@

moveit.enabled=@moveit.enabled@
moveit.host=@moveit.host@
moveit.path=@moveit.path@
moveit.user=@moveit.user@
moveit.pass=@moveit.pass@
moveit.root=@moveit.root@
moveit.url=@moveit.url@
```

and test.properties looks like

```
moveit.dir=D:\\data\\moveit
moveit.enabled=false
moveit.host=thmdsdev0.tsh.tho.com
moveit.path=/moveitdmz
moveit.user=muttt
moveit.pass=ssss
moveit.root=/Home/MeaningfulUse
moveit.url=https://thmdsdev00.tsh.tho.com/moveitdmz
```

I want through ant to read the value from test.properties for e.g moveit.user and paste it or add in the local.properties.template in place of @moveit.user@ and same for all variables.Then I will change the name of local.properties.template file to local.properties and move it other folder

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you can use [Filter Chain](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) and [Replace Tokens](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.html) to achieve this effect. For example:

```
<copy file="${PROP.your.path}/local.properties.template"
    tofile="${PROP.your.path.destination}/local.properties"
    overwrite="true">
    <filterchain>
        <replacetokens>
            <token key="@moveit.dir@" value="${moveit.dir}"/>
            <token key="@moveit.dir2@" value="${moveit.dir2}"/>
        </replacetokens>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the ant script in below manner and it is working fine.

```
<project name="replace_and_copy" basedir="." default="usage">
    <!--taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/-->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

    <macrodef name="copy-and-filter">
    <sequential>
      <copy tofile="local_for_test_copy.properties" file="templates/local.properties.test.template" overwrite="true">
        <filterset recurse="true">
          <filtersfile file="Properties/${deploy.env}/local_for_${deploy.env}.properties"/>
        </filterset>
      </copy>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

 <target name="env.copy.local.props">
  <copy-and-filter />
    <for param="host" list="${deploy.host}">
      <sequential>
        <copy todir="\\@{host}\${deploy.path}\conf\"
              file="local_for_test_copy.properties"
              overwrite="true"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
  </target>
</project>
```